# Error in FlatTreeControl.getDescendants in the mat tree angular

Tags: angular

Im trying to implement mat tree structure in my application with data coming from API. Im getting an error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at FlatTreeControl.getDescendants" which is in flat-tree-control.d.ts file. Please help me out with this. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The error is coming because you are calling the build File Tree function in the ngOninit. You need to call the function in constructor and then later on you can call it again in oninit while data camed through HTTP call. It will resolve the issue